# Issue with persisting data (stored in coredata) on tableview

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am having a tableview. There is a button on top on the click of which an alert with textField pops up and I am able to enter some data on the textField. On the click of 'OK', the content on alertview is populated in the tableview. I am also storing this data in CoreData.

But the issue is when I close the app or navigate to another screen, the data in the tableview is wiped out while it should have persisted and remained on the screen even while navigating to another screen or closing the app since the data was stored in CoreData.

What should be done...? Please help...

Also, this is how I am saving the data:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
          return    }
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Category", in: managedContext)
let category = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

category.setValue(categoryName, forKeyPath: "categoryName")
category.setValue(categoryId, forKey: "categoryId")

  do {

  try managedContext.save()
  self.managedObject.append(category as! Category)
    } catch let error as NSError {
   print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
   }
```

Comment: Please show your code for a better response

Comment: Did you save the managed object context?

Comment: @Paulw11 Should the data be fetched so that it will be shown on the tableview anytime I visit the screen...?

Comment: Yes, how do you load the data for the table view?

Comment: self.anArrayToHoldValues.append(self.myString)


self.categoryTableView.reloadData()

Comment: @Paulw11 this is how I load the data..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your old data which you have entered in coredata is not visible on TableView , If this is the case then it working correctly , Because TableView doesn't persist data. Data is persisted in coreData , You just need to fetch the data from Coredata and load it in TableView.

Use below code to fetch

```
var category  = [Category]() // Where Category = your NSManaged Class

    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Category")

    do {
        category = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Category]
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch category: \(error)")
    }

// Then you can use this array to populate UITableView Datasource and Call.
arrTableView = category
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: It isn't working, @sudhir kumar. The syntax of the 3rd line seems improper.

Comment: Thanks for telling me , I have edited my code. Hopes this help

Comment: seems there is still an issue, @Sudhir kumar. This line throws an error 'arrTableView = category' because the array which has the elements of the tableview is a type of string and 'category' is of type 'Category'. Changing the string type of array into an array of type Category affects a lot of other places also...:(